# Timeout in Pdf-html when running on Google Cloud Function

Tags: pdf, google-cloud-functions, phantomjs, serverless, pdfhtml

We've created a Cloud Function that generates a PDF. The library that we're using is

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

The problem is when we try to execute the

```
.create()
```

method it times out with the following errors

```
"Error: html-pdf: PDF generation timeout. Phantom.js script did not exit.
    at Timeout.execTimeout (/srv/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:91:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
```

This works fine on localhost but happens when we deploy the function on GCP.

Some solutions we've already tried:

**Solution #1**
Yes we've updated the timeout settings to

```
const options = {
        format: "A3",
        orientation: "portrait",
        timeout: "100000"
        // zoomFactor: "0.5"

        // orientation: "portrait"
      };
```

and it still doesn't work.

here's the final snippet that triggers the PDF function

```
const options = {
        format: "A3",
        orientation: "portrait",
        timeout: "100000"
        // zoomFactor: "0.5"

        // orientation: "portrait"
      };
      try {
        // let pdfRes = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Before pdf.create()")

        let pdfResponse = await pdf.create(html, options).toFile(localPDFFile, async function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }

          console.log('response of pdf.create(): ', res);
          let uploadBucket = await bucket.upload(localPDFFile, {
            metadata: { contentType: "application/octet-stream" }
          });

          let docRef = await db
            .collection("Organizations")
            .doc(context.params.orgId)
            .collection("regulations")
            .doc(context.params.regulationId)
            .collection("reports")
            .doc(context.params.reportId);

          await docRef.update({
            pdf: {
              status: "created",
              reportName: pdfName
            }
          });
        });
 } catch (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error);
      }
``
```

Comment: On the [best pratices doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#ensure_http_functions_send_an_http_response) it's mentioned that if no response is sent back it could cause a timeout, or unpredictable behavior, this may be affecting you

Comment: Actually we're using trigger based functions
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions]

Comment: This would be the case when we're using an Http function, but not in ours.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many cases like this even in my current project we use step functions (when cloud functions needs more computational power we divide them into chunks i.e mini cloud functions).
But i think step functions will not work in your case either because you are using single module. 
In your case you should use compute engine to perform this operation.

Comment: Unfortunately we couldn't solve this issue so we had to resort to a pdf on demand service to handle this matter.

Comment: Yeah ! that's what i think will be right solution for this issue .

Answer (score 1):

Using promise, We can fix this timeout error

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');

var options = {
  height: "10.5in", // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  width: "8in" // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  "timeout": 600000
};
var document = {
  html: html1,
  path: resolvedPath + "/" + filename,
  data: {}
};


var create = function(document, options) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Compiles a template
    var html = Handlebars.compile(document.html)(document.data);
    var pdfPromise = pdf.create(html, options);

    // Create PDF from html template generated by handlebars
    // Output will be PDF file
    pdfPromise.toFile(document.path, (err, res) => {
        if (!err)
            resolve(res);
        else
            reject(err);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a problem with the html, my problem was that I had an image source linked to a deleted image in a server and that was what caused the time out, I solved it by putting the image in the server's route and that was it, I hope this to be useful to someone